# Make Fail when installing uuid pecl extension on OSX

Tags: macos, uuid, pecl

So not to familiar with installing extensions by here is my process and the moment of fail.

```
$ sudo pecl install uuid
```

then all is good until...

```
creating libtool
appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
running: make
/bin/sh /private/var/tmp/pear-build-root/uuid-1.0.2/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/private/var/tmp/apache_mod_php/apache_mod_php-53~1/Build/tmp/pear/temp/uuid -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/private/var/tmp/pear-build-root/uuid-1.0.2/include -I/private/var/tmp/pear-build-root/uuid-1.0.2/main -I/private/var/tmp/apache_mod_php/apache_mod_php-53~1/Build/tmp/pear/temp/uuid -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/include  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /private/var/tmp/apache_mod_php/apache_mod_php-53~1/Build/tmp/pear/temp/uuid/uuid.c -o uuid.lo
mkdir .libs
 cc -I. "-I/private/var/tmp/apache_mod_php/apache_mod_php-53~1/Build/tmp/pear/temp/uuid" -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/private/var/tmp/pear-build-root/uuid-1.0.2/include -I/private/var/tmp/pear-build-root/uuid-1.0.2/main "-I/private/var/tmp/apache_mod_php/apache_mod_php-53~1/Build/tmp/pear/temp/uuid" -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/include -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c "/private/var/tmp/apache_mod_php/apache_mod_php-53~1/Build/tmp/pear/temp/uuid/uuid.c"  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/uuid.o
/private/var/tmp/apache_mod_php/apache_mod_php-53~1/Build/tmp/pear/temp/uuid/uuid.c: In function ‘zm_startup_uuid’:
/private/var/tmp/apache_mod_php/apache_mod_php-53~1/Build/tmp/pear/temp/uuid/uuid.c:89: error: ‘UUID_TYPE_DCE_TIME’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/private/var/tmp/apache_mod_php/apache_mod_php-53~1/Build/tmp/pear/temp/uuid/uuid.c:89: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
/private/var/tmp/apache_mod_php/apache_mod_php-53~1/Build/tmp/pear/temp/uuid/uuid.c:89: error: for each function it appears in.)
/private/var/tmp/apache_mod_php/apache_mod_php-53~1/Build/tmp/pear/temp/uuid/uuid.c:90: error: ‘UUID_TYPE_DCE_RANDOM’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/private/var/tmp/apache_mod_php/apache_mod_php-53~1/Build/tmp/pear/temp/uuid/uuid.c: In function ‘zif_uuid_create’:
/private/var/tmp/apache_mod_php/apache_mod_php-53~1/Build/tmp/pear/temp/uuid/uuid.c:168: error: ‘UUID_TYPE_DCE_TIME’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/private/var/tmp/apache_mod_php/apache_mod_php-53~1/Build/tmp/pear/temp/uuid/uuid.c:171: error: ‘UUID_TYPE_DCE_RANDOM’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/private/var/tmp/apache_mod_php/apache_mod_php-53~1/Build/tmp/pear/temp/uuid/uuid.c:181: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘long int’
make: *** [uuid.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow this tutorial --

http://unrealexpectations.com/blog/2010/04/mamp-pecluuid-module-working-on-snow-leopard/

When you go to make the patch make sure the file to patch are entered correctly, you want to have it be tests/uuid_mac.phpt

If that doesn't work make sure you have you have your php.ini configured with the extension_dir and have the extension=uuid.so there as well.

This also works for OS X 10.7

Answer (score 1):

You will need an updated version of uuid from `util-linux`. It is available on Homebrew.

```
brew install util-linux
```

But `util-linux` is a keg-only package and will not be symlinked to `/usr/local`. Hence you will have to specify the following path when prompted for uuid installation directory

```
/usr/local/opt/util-linux
```

For unattended installations, you can use

```
printf "/usr/local/opt/util-linux" | pecl install uuid
```